# Blog page shows the whole blog post instead of the excerpt or summary with the feature image only

Tags: posts, themes, blog, e-commerce, blog-page

My ecommerce website is built on the storefront theme. I've started its blog, however, the blog post is not being showed as an excerpt on the blog page. Instead, it appears as the complete post. Also, how can I improve its appearance, i e , the text extends to the edges of the page with wordpress built-in template?

Comment: is this not a setting on the reading/general page? Note that 3rd party theme dev support questions are offtopic here, you can't ask for help or ask questions about a 3rd party product/theme you bought or downloaded here